# Setting up a 3D matrix in R and accessing certain elements

Tags: arrays, r, element

I am trying to set up a 3D matrix in R. I guess this is an easy one. However, I didn't find a solution so far.
Let's say we want to create a 365x6x4 matrix.
Also crucial form me is how I can change one entry in the matrix.
Let's say we want to assign the value 204 to the element [304,5,2].

Comment: 3D matrix? Wouldn't that be a 3D array rather?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this:

```r
ar <- array(someData, c(365, 6, 4));  
ar[304,5,2] <- 204;
```

where `someData` might be

```
someData <- rep(0, 365*6*4);
```

or even better maybe

```
someData <- rep(NaN, 365*6*4);
```

Comment: No problem, you must be thinking of C :)

Comment: Also, you don't actually need the `rep` command in situations like the ones you mention - the duplication is automatic. Try it! :)

Comment: @TimP: Thanks, I thought about, but wasn't sure and apparently lazy to try it out myself. :) Haven't used R for a while and it shows :)

Comment: @Andrie: Thanks, I'm trying :)

Comment: Yep, its called *recycling* in R-speak; the shorter object is recycled an number of times to match the length of the longer. If the number of times is non-integer, a warning about incompatible lengths is issued, but the recycled object is still used.

Comment: +1 Gavin. A nice illustration is `all(c(1,2)==c(1,2,1,2))` which R thinks is TRUE!

Answer (score 20):

A matrix is a special 2-dimensional case of an array.  (Quoting from the help for `?matrix`).

So, you need `array`:

```
x <- array(rep(1, 365*5*4), dim=c(365, 5, 4))
str(x)
num [1:365, 1:5, 1:4] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Set a specific value:

```
x[305, 5, 2] <- 204
```

Print one slice:

```
x[305, , ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1  204    1    1
```

Comment: First rep command is redundant here of course. See my answer for an example where you can see the whole of the array :)

Comment: @TimP It might be redundant but it is also bleedingly obvious what the code does. Relying on behaviour or feature *X* of R may distract from the real issue one is attempting to illustrate in an Answer. Making the point once adds to the overall content of this Q. Doing it twice seem petty.

Comment: Sorry that you feel it's petty, though Havelock certainly appreciated the pointer - so I'm glad I mentioned it to him too :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this simple example (have made the example a fairly small one so it's clear what's going on - I explain below how to tweak it for your precise question!)...

```
m = array(1:60, dim=c(3,4,5))

m[2,1,5]
[1] 50

m[2,1,5] = -50

m[2,1,5]
[1] -50
```

Type `m` to see the whole 3d array :)

In your example, you'd set up your initial array as `m = array(NA, dim=c(365,6,4))` (this will fill it with NAs to start with - do you have data to fill it up with?) And the assignment is `m[304,5,2] = 204`, of course :)

Comment: To clarify, `m[2,1,5]` is initially 50 (due to the way `m` is populated) and becomes -50 after the change is made (`m[2,1,5]=-50`). Type `m` to see the whole 3d array :)