# Combine 2-D matrix to 3-D matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

```
x <- array(1:5,c(5,1))
y <- array(6:10,c(5,1))
z <- cbind(x,y)
```

I want to reshape this matrix z to a 3-D matrix like something [5,1,2]
There are lots of examples about how to do this in Python.But I do not know how to do it in R.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961141/setting-up-a-3d-matrix-in-r-and-accessing-certain-elements

Comment: Thank you so much!